# Opening a File with an unknown name. C#

Tags: c#, file

I am trying to open a file in C#. I am not sure what the file name will be. The user must enter a year, and this will determine the file name. For instance, if the user enters 2012 the file name is `@"C:\Users\Marina\Documents\Excel Files\2012.txt"`.

My code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

string yearEntered = newDate.Text;
var openFile = File.Open(@"C: \Users\Marina\Documents\Excel Files" + yearEntered + ".txt");
```

`newDate` is a textbox I have created on `Form1`.

I get an error saying:

> No overload for method 'Open' takes 1 arguments". Error code CS1501.

Comment: The solution is in the error message already. The method 'Open'  needs more arguments. Check MSDN for the parameters of File.Open: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9skfh7s(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Check the docs and Intellisense, they show what parameters must be passed to the function call.

Comment: Thank you! This cleared it up!

Comment: Don't you guys refer documentation or search in google atleast before posting a question?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is quite clear, you haven't specified the correct number of arguments for the `Open` method.  Try adding a FileMode.

```
File.Open(@"C: \Users\Marina\Documents\Excel Files" + yearEntered + ".txt", FileMode.Open);
```

Comment: Thank a lot man! I'm new to C# so little things take me hours to figure out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter FileMode after the file name, example:

```
File.Open(@"d:\file1.txt", FileMode.Create);
```

Take a look at this link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode(v=vs.110).aspx